# How to automatically connect Mac's Wi-Fi to iPhone's hotspot

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, mac

I am searching for a solution to automatically connect my MacBook Air to my iPhone hotspot. I don't like to connect manually every time. Is there any way to connect automatically.

Can I write a shell script file which will try to connect to my Hotspot so that I can add that task to system startup? Does that work? Is there any command to connect to a hotspot?

Answer (score 21):

After connecting to the iPhone AP you should go in Network Preference and enable "Automatically join this network", as shown in the picture. You may also want to click "Advanced" and move the AP to change its priority (for example if you are at home you want the Mac to connect to your home's WiFi and not to the phone. So you should put the iPhone AP below the one at home - and/or work if any).

I have enabled it myself, but for some reasons it didn't seem to stick. Right now, again in "Advanced", I have deleted the "RedPlanet" AP, applied the changes, connected my MBP to my iPhone again re-enabling the "Automatically Join" flag.

That should be it, hopefully, unless being a connection from a mobile phone (thus with a data plan) macOS treats it differently (or if it is bugged. It worked randomly in the last couple of days that I enabled it)

[image]

Comment: Worked for me! This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Does not work on MacOS 10.14

Comment: Does not work for 10.15.x

Comment: "Automatically join this network" doesnt work on macos12

Comment: I'm on Moneterey 12.1, and came here searching for a solution. My iPhone disconnects so often it's ridiculous. I noticed that the mentioned checkbox "Automatically join this network" doesn't get saved.

Comment: Does not work with Mac OS 13.5 (Ventura) -- I haven't tried it yet but reading the script created by @Yunlong Liu, looks like it should work.

Answer (score 7):

While you cannot connect automatically, you can streamline the process by using [these directions from Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204681):

> Use Instant Hotspot with any Mac, iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch that meets the Continuity system requirements. It
>   works when your devices are near each other and set up as follows:
>
> - Your iPhone or iPad (Wi-Fi + Cellular) has an activated carrier plan    providing Personal Hotspot service.
> - Each device is signed in to iCloud with the same Apple ID.
> - Each device has Bluetooth turned on.
> - Each device has Wi-Fi turned on.
>
> To connect to your Personal Hotspot:
>
> - On Mac, use the Wi-Fi status menu in the menu bar to choose the name    of the iPhone or iPad providing your Personal Hotspot.
> - On iPad, iPod touch, or even another iPhone, go to Settings > Wi-Fi,    then tap the name of the iPhone or iPad providing your
>     Personal    Hotspot.
>
> If you're asked for a password when connecting, make sure that your
>   devices are set up as described above. The Wi-Fi status icon   in the
>   menu bar shows the Personal Hotspot icon  as long as your device
>   remains connected to your Personal Hotspot.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone still interested in this, I wrote a service utilizing shell script to automatically connect to hotspot. Star if you like it.

https://github.com/OnDaShouldersOfGiants/auto-hotspot

Comment: Is this still maintained, and does it work with macOS Sonoma? The instructions don't seem to match the actual scripts in the repo. For example, the instructions mention `uninstall.sh`, but there is no such file in the repo.

Comment: That part of the README has apparently not been updated -- I read the install.sh and to uninstall, run the install script with the flag "u" or "uninstall" to uninstall.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

When this option "Allow Others to Join" is enabled on your phone, MacOS will be able to automatically connect to your iPhones hotspot, if configured to do so in settings, like any other network.

Without this setting enabled, MacOS will not connect automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can't connect to WiFi hotspot, but anyway you can automatically connect to hotspot via cable.

- Connect iPhone, open Network preferences
- Drag & Drop iPhone USB on the top
- Uncheck *Disable unless needed*

[image: preferences]

Comment: I am posting this from my MBP connected to the Internet through my iPhone via WiFi. No need for password either, since both devices use the same iCloud ID by @drivec

Answer (score 0):

**MacOS 14.0, iOS 17.3.1**

On your Mac: just connect to your hotspot, then go to System Settings, go to Wi-Fi, you'll see your hotspot.

Now, you press three dots in the circle icon and there is **Auto-Join**. Just click, that's it.

Comment: It’s much more helpful if you reference the version of iOS rather than an obscure year like “2024”. Which version does it apply to?  iOS 15, 16, or 17?

Answer (score -1):

In the iPhone Settings -> Personal Hotspot - uncheck "Maximise Compatibility"

Answer (score -3):

nice one! I will try to use it. Is there a way to make install easier? I guess for most of us your description is too complicated.
But still thank you for your effort!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. You’ve posted this as an answer, which is only for things that directly answer the question asked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/321870)